# Can Spring OAuth2 ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer authenticates with database?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am new to Spring Boot OAuth2 framework.
I have the following working when authenticating incoming requests to ask for token.
The "withClient" and "secret" are both hard-coded and I want that to query against database
like MySQL.  I like different clients to have different login/secret pairs.

Is this possible?  Can someone provide example?  thanks

```
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
               .withClient("clientA")
               .secret("secret")
               .accessTokenValiditySeconds(2000)        // expire time for access token
               .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(-1)         // expire time for refresh token
               .scopes("read", "write")                         // scope related to resource server
               .authorizedGrantTypes("password");     

    }
```

Comment: Yes, you can. database schema is available at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#dbschema-oauth2-client

Comment: @Thirumal   This schema is good.  But I am following the details.  For instance, where is the secret being stored in the DB?  This table does not have such a field.   Also, how is this table related to    https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/test/resources/schema.sql  ?